# Twitter Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2, twitter-oauth

I'm using Struts2 in Google App Engine. 
In my Action:

```
public String execute(){
    oauth_callback = REDIRECT_URI;
    consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY;
    consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In my Struts.xml

```
<result type="redirect">
    <param name="location">https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=${oauth_callback}&amp;consumer_key=${consumer_key}&amp;consumer_secret=${consumer_secret}</param>
</result>
```

Im getting error:

```
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

Am I missing a parameter to passed to oath/request_token?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any API for oAuth or doing on your own?

Comment: i recommend to use Scribe to handle Oauth functionality.its very light weight and quite easy to use and we are using it in almost each and every app